# [U-SQL]][FlexExtractor] I Can't join. The expressions must both be columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am working with Cortana Analytics Suite. Currently analyzing data of a Data Lake store with a visual studio data lake analytics project with files containing hundred of columns. After reading the u-sql docs I found a flex extractor to help with this problem (hundred columns). The flex extractor was working perfectly with one table. The problem starts with joining tables, I am getting this error when compile:

"Error E_CSC_USER_JOINCOLUMNSEXPECTEDONEACHSIDEOFCONDITION: The expressions map[0] and map_2[0] on each side of the comparison must both be columns."

I have two extractors like this:

```
@data = EXTRACT map SqlMap<Int32,string>
    FROM @input
    USING new USQLFlexExtractor.FlexExtractor();

@data_2 = EXTRACT map_2 SqlMap<Int32,string>
    FROM @input_2
    USING new USQLFlexExtractor.FlexExtractor();

@output =  SELECT map[0], map[2], map_2[1]
FROM @data AS data
LEFT JOIN @data_2 AS data_2 ON map[0] == map_2[0]
```

I am following this example (usql script and c# code behind): *https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/FlexibleSchemaExtractor/FlexibleSchemaExtractor*

I have even tried a different approach with the Combine expression but I got the same error.

Any ideas why?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U-Sql does not support derived columns in join conditions. You can try to use an intermediate result set like this:

```
@dataExtract = EXTRACT map SqlMap<Int32,string>
    FROM @input
    USING new USQLFlexExtractor.FlexExtractor();

@dataExtract_2 = EXTRACT map_2 SqlMap<Int32,string>
    FROM @input_2
    USING new USQLFlexExtractor.FlexExtractor();

@data =
    SELECT map[0] AS map0,
           map[2] AS map2
FROM @dataExtract;

@data_2 =
    SELECT map[0] AS map2_0,
           map[1] AS map2_1
FROM @dataExtract_2;

@output =  SELECT map0, map2, map21
FROM @data AS data
LEFT JOIN @data_2 AS data_2 ON map0 == map2_0;
```

Comment: The reason why we do not support this directly is, to make the cost explicit. By moving it into a separate expression, the query will be split into possibly several vertices, thus making the query somewhat more expensive than you may expect. Please let us know whether you would prefer the cost be explicit or if we did the rewrite for you at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.